# Docker container stdout, stderr is being truncated. Is there a way to stop this?

Tags: docker

From php code running in Docker container we are dumping out a long Json string to stdout. It is showing up on the container log in the terminal but after 3 lines it is truncated with an ellipsis. Is there a setting to stop this truncation? Or another way to get access to the complete stdout/stderr stream? Thanks

Comment: check if related https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1229

Comment: thanks, I did see that but not related. My output has been deliberately truncated with 'ellipsis ...' as if to indicate that it is too long

Comment: Do you have a reproducer, Dockerfile, `docker run` and so?